# Angular.js / Using ng-submit with form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have an HTML page with form block

```
<div>
   <form>
       <div class="row">
         ...
           <input required> a </input>
         ...
       <div>
       <div class="row">
         ...
           <input required> b </input>
         ...
       <div>
       <div>
            <button ng-click="expand()"> Expand </button>
            <button type="submit" ng-submit="create()"> Start </button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

When I click on start, and a or b are empties, message is shown: `"Please fill out this field"` (which it is the desire behavior) . But when I fill out this field, and click again, `create()` is not submitted and I get the following error: `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable`.

I try also in this way:

```
   <div>
     <form ng-submit="create()">
       <div class="row">
         ...
        </div>
       <div>
            <button ng-click="expand()"> Expand </button>
            <button type="submit"> Start </button>
       </div>
      </form>  
    </div>
```

But then even if I click on Expand, `create()` is executed instead of `expand()`.

I also try yo change ng-submit to ng-click, but then it doesn't validate that the fields is fill out.

My purpose is that `create()` will NOT be executed if one of the fields is empty, and proper message will be shown.

Comment: Have you tried adding `type="button"` prop for that Expand button?

Comment: @BatuZet: No, Should I?

Comment: Yes. That's why i asked actually bro :)

Comment: @BatuZet: I add this to the Expand button, but I still get `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.` when I click on Start and the field are not empty

Comment: That's because type button is the default

Comment: How about giving a name to form?

Comment: ng-submit should be in the form tag. What does your controller look like?

Comment: @TharinMeggettII: In the controller I have the function `create()`. With ng-click is working well (but it doesn't do the validations), so I don't think its related to the controller.

Comment: But for the 2nd code section, you dont get the `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable` right? Have you tried adding `type="button"` for that one too?

Comment: @BatuZet: The situation now is that I have <form ng-submit="Create()" name="validate"> .... <button type="submit"> Start </button> <button type="button"> Expand </button> and when I fill the fields I get: `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <div>
   <form ng-submit="submit()">
     <div class="row">
       <input required type="text" ng-model="text" name="text_a">A</input>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <input required type="text" ng-model="text" name="text_b">B</input>
     </div>
     <div>
       <button ng-click="expand()"> Expand </button>
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />
     </div>
   </form>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Create is a button, not an input. I try to change it in this way, but the same error raised.

Comment: I see, normally this happens when an invalid field is hidden and the invalid event isn't handled. I'd usually tell to you to put novalidate in the form tag.

Comment: But I want to validate the inputs

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do form validation is like this:
Give your form a name attribute

```
<form name="myForm">
```

Add the required attribute to your inputs.

Disable your button with

```
<button ng-disable="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="create()">Submit</button>
```

If one of your inputs is invalid you can likewise display a message with a span or div that has the ng-show="myForm.$invalid" attribute.

I'm not clear on exactly what you are doing with the data from the inputs.